# Conditional formatting if cell past date and another cell empty

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have tried a suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059799/excel-format-cell-if-cell-contains-date-less-than-today), but for some reason its not working with what I need.

I need Due date to highlight if the date is today or earlier AND if Completed isn't indicating "yes" (or if the cell is blank)

I tried `=IF(F2="",B2>=TODAY()) and =IF(B2>=TODAY(),F2="")` but neither worked.

(Column B is my date, Column F is where it says yes or blank)

Answer (score 0):

Please try selecting ColumnB and applying this CF formula rule:

```
=AND($B1<=TODAY(),$B1<>"",$F1<>"yes")
```

[image: SO30505946 example]